# Looping with scanner

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am trying to make a triangular numbers generator that asks the user how many triangular numbers it would like them to generate.
These are my errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:862)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
    at TriangularNumbers.main(TriangularNumbers.java:11)


    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class TriangularNumbers {
        public static void main(String args[]) {
            while(true){
                long tnumber = 1L;
                long amount = 2L;
                System.out.println("Welcome to the triangular numbers           calculator!");
                System.out.println("Type in the amount of triangular numbers to be generated!");
                Scanner reps = new Scanner(System.in);
                long repeats = reps.nextInt();
                reps.close();
                long i = 0L;
                while (i < repeats) {
                    i = i + 1;
                    System.out.println(i + ". " + tnumber);
                    tnumber = tnumber + amount;
                    amount = (amount + 1);
                }
                System.out.println("Done generating!");
            }
        }

    }
```

Everything works fine until it reaches the stage of the second user input.

Comment: uhhhh sorry wrong dupe, don´t do `reps.close();` in the loop, you´re closing the `System.in` Stream and wont be able to input anymore afterwards.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next(), nextInt() or other nextFoo() methods](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-nextint-or-other-nextfoo)

Answer (score -1):

Why cant you try this way.?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TriangularNumbers {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner reps = new Scanner(System.in);
        while(true){
            long tnumber = 1L;
            long amount = 2L;
            System.out.println("Welcome to the triangular numbers           calculator!");
            System.out.println("Type in the amount of triangular numbers to be generated!");

            long repeats = reps.nextInt();
            if(reps == 0L) break; //Considering reps ==0 as the terminating condition to get out of the loop
            long i = 0L;
            while (i < repeats) {
                i = i + 1;
                System.out.println(i + ". " + tnumber);
                tnumber = tnumber + amount;
                amount = (amount + 1);
            }
            System.out.println("Done generating!");
            reps.nextLine(); // Has to be there in case of run out of tokens
        }
        reps.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: reps.close() will be unreachable

Comment: As Amer said I don't think reps.close() would ever occur, or does that not matter?

Comment: It was a solution to your problem. Logic always belong to the the coder. :D

Comment: It says that long and scanner can't go together.

Answer (score -2):

Pleae change code like this:

```
 long tnumber = 1L;
    long amount = 2L;
    System.out.println("Welcome to the triangular numbers           calculator!");
    System.out.println("Type in the amount of triangular numbers to be generated!");
    Scanner reps = new Scanner(System.in);
    long repeats = reps.nextInt();
    reps.close();
    long i = 0L;
    do {
        i = i + 1;
        System.out.println(i + ". " + tnumber);
        tnumber = tnumber + amount;
        amount = (amount + 1);
        System.out.println("Done generating!");
    } while (i < repeats);
```